# How to create line Hightchart from CSV where two columns of data are used as tooltip text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is a multi-part question, so please forgive the length of the question.

I'm attempting to create a chart that will plot a patient's height, weight, and BMI as separate series for multiple dates. I want to pull the data in using CSV for testing purposes before migrating to a server. I'm attempting to get it to work similar to this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g7d4W/9/), but haven't been successful so far.

Here's one version of my code with the data hard coded:

```
$(function () { 
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Patient Measurements'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Measurements'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    var data = "ID,PATIENT_NAME,DATA_DATE,HEIGHT,WEIGHT,BMI\n" +
               "1,\"Doe,John\",1/1/2013 00:00:00,65,185,30.78224852\n" +
               "1,\"Doe,John\",1/2/2013 00:00:00,65,184,30.61585799\n" +
               "1,\"Doe,John\",2/1/2013 00:00:00,65,181,30.11668639\n" +
               "1,\"Doe,John\",2/2/2013 00:00:00,65,180,29.95029585\n"

    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var first = lines.shift().split(',');
    var series_holder = [];
    for (var = i, i < first.length, i++) {
        var s = {
            data: []
        };
        series_holder.push(s);
    }

    $.each (lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        $.each (items, function(itemNo, item){
            // If itemNo is the row/column iteration object, then start at column 2
            if (itemNo >= 2) {
                // Subtract the column from the itemNo to get a zero-based series_holder
                series_holder[itemNo - 2].data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
        });
    });
    options.series = series_holder;

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

The example should plot three lines (one for height, weight, and BMI) with four data points apiece (for each date).

I know the data in my example is not formatted based on Highcharts recommendations, but I need to be able to grab the ID and PATIENT_NAME fields from the CSV and use them in the tooltip for the series, so that the ID and PATIENT_NAME will identify the patient regardless of the data point you hover over. I understand that I could just display this in a DIV or something on the page, but I wanted to be able to do this because I have ideas for other things I could display in the tooltip if I can figure out how to get this to work.

From reviewing Highcharts site, I believe that all I would need to do to implement my code for a CSV, would be to add the following code instead of *var data = "..."* in my code above:

```
$.get(inputData, function(data) {
    // Check for data
    if (data.value != "") {
        alert("No data to retrieve!");
        return(0);
    }
```

I'm not very well-versed with Javascript, jQuery, or Highcharts, but I'm doing my best to learn quickly. I realize that there are likely a number of mistakes in my code (some intentional, like parseFloat for non-float data types, so I can learn how to handle/parse different data types), so I appreciate everyone's patience.

Thanks for your help.
I've been playing with this some more and, after doing a lot of debugging to determine how the data is handled, I came up with the following code. I thought this might be a simplified version that might better get my point across.

```
$(function () { 
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Patient Measurements'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Measurements'
        }
    },
    series: []
};

var data = "ID;PATIENT_NAME;DATA_DATE;AVG_HEIGHT;AVG_WEIGHT;BMI;WEIGHT_STATUS\n"+"1;DOE,JOHN;2012-12-29 00:00:00;65;185;30.7822485207101;Obese\n"+"1;DOE,JOHN;2013-01-12 00:00:00;65;184;30.6158579881657;Obese\n"+"1;DOE,JOHN;2013-02-09 00:00:00;65;181;30.1166863905325;Obese\n";
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');
var first = lines.shift().split(';');
var series_holder = [];
$.each (lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(';');
    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
        if (itemNo == 3) {
            options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        }
        else if (itemNo > 3 && itemNo < 7) {
            series_holder[itemNo-4].data.push(parseFloat(item));
        }
    });
});      

for (var i = 4; i < first.length - 1; i++) {
    var s = {
        data: []
    };

    s.name = first[i].replace(/AVG_/g,"");
    series_holder.push(s);
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

});

The x-Axis should be the date values under DATE_DATE.

The series/lines should be the following:

1. Height
2. Weight
3. BMI

The data for the plot points is in column index 4 (AVG_HEIGHT) to 6 (BMI) after the header row.

Here's a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beacon5/HDrhv/4/) that I got to work that is similar to what I want to do...I just can't get it to work for my specific data.

I'll hold off on the tooltip and CSV portions of my question for now. I'd really like to get something of mine working so I know I'm on the right track.

Comment: your question has to be more specific.. read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for some pointers

Comment: I'm asking three questions that are part of the same problem. The 1st question is, how do I get the chart to work for the sample data I provided directly in the js. 

The 2nd question is, how do I get the chart to work if I import the data from an external CSV file. 

The 3rd question is, how do I get the first two columns in the CSV data to appear as additional text in the tooltip for each plot point. As I explained in my post, there should be 3 series, one each for height, weight, and BMI, where the first two columns of data, after the header row, need to be in the tooltip.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but more a tip: Highcharts have a plugin (modules/data.src.js) that handle parsing of csv data that should get you started. It will automatically use the column names as series names, and it also tries to guess the types of the columns (datetime/number/category).

Have a look at the src on [github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/data.src.js), and the demo example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/SnLFj/):

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv1').innerHTML
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Categorized CSV data'
    }
});
```

Comment: Like you said, it's not a complete answer, but I can see it being useful, so thank you for letting me know about it. Just so I'm clear, where the example says **csv: document.getElementById('csv1').innerHTML**, I could use **url()** to import the CSV, correct?

Comment: The csv property should be a string containing the csv. So if the url() function returns such a string then it should work.